# How to iterate through the articles to scrape the full content?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to collect the headline and conent from the news website (https://www.nusabali.com/search?keyword=umkm). I got the headline and the content summary/preview, but I want to retrieve the full article. I see that I would need to click into each article return to previous page and continue to the next article but I couldn't figure out how. Thank you for any help. Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

# empty list
headlines_list = []
content_list = []

# chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))

driver.get('https://www.nusabali.com/search?keyword=umkm')

count = 0

while (count<5):
    try:
        time.sleep(1)
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#main-content > div.wrapper.clearfix > div.col-a.pull-left > section.widget-area-2.pull-right > div > div > div.row > div > button'))))
        count +=1
    except: 
        break

# Select all the parent elements that contain the headline and content
parents = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".card-deck > .card")

# Iterate through each parent element
for parent in parents:
    try:
        # headline
        headline = parent.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "h5")
        headlines_list.append(headline.text)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        headlines_list.append(None)
    try:
        # content
        content = parent.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "p")
        content_list.append(content.text)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        content_list.append(None)

while len(headlines_list) > len(content_list):
    headlines_list.pop()
while len(headlines_list) < len(content_list):
    content_list.pop()

# create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Headline': headlines_list, 'Content': content_list})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I see that I would need to click into each article return to previous page and continue to the next article

Not necessarily. Instead, you could just gather all links into a list that you can loop through and scrape.

```py
# while....[ load more ]
article_links = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.row div.row h5>a[href]")
article_links = list(set([l.get_attribute('href') for l in article_links])) ## set <-> unique

for url in article_links:
    driver.get(url)
    ### SCRAPE ARTICLE ###
```

**Note:** I can't find any elements with selector `.card-deck > .card`, but `div.row.feature-items` or [excluding thumbnail area] `div.row div.row` seems to work for article containers.

---

Btw, about

> ```py
>         driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#main-content > div.wrapper.clearfix > div.col-a.pull-left > section.widget-area-2.pull-right > div > div > div.row > div > button'))))
> ```

Simply `button.load-mores:has(+a.load-more-basic)` [or even just **`button.load-mores`**] should be enough to select the load-more button.

Comment: Thanks so much! This saves me a lot of time, can't thank you enough for this.